# How to classify this PDE: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u^3+au^3\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}\right)=\frac bu$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

I'm a physicist, and while working on a problem I ended up with the following PDE describing my physical property $u(x,t)$,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} 
\left( u^3 + a u^3 \frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3} \right)
= \frac{b}{u}
$$
where $a$ and  $b$ are constants. The property $u$ should physically always be positive.

Now, in order to look up helpful material on analysis and numerical solutions, I would need to classify/name this kind of PDE. Does this PDE belong to some known class/type/family of equations? 
If it's helpful, perhaps disregard the right hand side term, and we can call it an "Equation of type X with a source term".

I would also be interesting in useful ways of rewriting this PDE, of course.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've looked at PDEs, but this seems to be some sort of non-linear, driven, advection-hyperdiffusion PDE. Advection refers to overall bulk movement ($u^3$ term) and the hyperdiffusion comes from the fourth derivative.

Comment: The tag ([tag:differential-equations]) is intended for questions about ordinary differential equations, there is a separate tag for [tag:pde]s; see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/differential-equations/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)